# Why is this foreground block executed before the background block if it's written later in the code?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

{ echo "1" ;
  sleep 3 ;
  echo "2"
} &
{ echo "a"
  sleep 1
  echo "b"
}
```

The output is

```
a
1
b
2
```

Why?
Shouldn't echo "1" be executed immediately?
Why the output is not

```
1
a
b
2
```

Comment: Once you put something in the background, you have multiple processes running simultaneously, with no guarantees about relative ordering between them. If you ran this code on a system with different performance characteristics, or just with the system competing with a different set of other processes for CPU time or otherwise (effectively) differences in random chance, you could get different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some time to run a new process to execute the background code. Also, the output doesn't have to be the same every time you run the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would say, it could be both outputs. And even any output with only constraints being that `a` is before `1` and `b` is before `2`:

`a 1 b 2`, `b 2 a 1`, `a b 1 2`, `a b 2 1`, `b a 1 2`, `b a 2 1`.

However, it is likely `b` could be output before `a`, because the `echo b` is evaluated by the script's shell, not by a forked/cloned sub-shell...

Comment: Only forked; there's no `exec()` call here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, corrected. In fact on my system, clone() is used - Linux specific system call.